# Use of Bootstrap Container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, containers

I have a question about which is the best way to use containers under Bootstrap.  I have 4 options below as an example and would like to know which is the better way to approach using containers.  Are the differences just style over substance?  Does the order that classes are specified matter and if so what order is best, localy defined first or last?

```
<!-- Latest JQuery; Must be loaded before Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

.section-1
{
    background-color: #2f5571;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #fdfcfc;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 20px; 
    margin-top: 20px; 
}

</style>


<div class="section-1">
    <p>Some text 1</p>
</div>


<div class="section-1 container">
    <p>Some text 2</p>
</div>


<div class="container section-1">
    <p>Some text 3</p>
</div>


<div class="section-1">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Some text 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would anyone down vote this?  This is a legitimate question regarding how to use Bootstrap/CSS most effectively and correctly.  As a matter of fact there are 7,858 questions on SO regarding the use of Bootstrap containers...

Comment: what you mean effectively ?  rendering? bootstrap is not effective for rendering time at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option #1 does not make use of the the container/grid system -- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/ -- so in the context of the correct usage of Bootstrap's libraries (specifically containers) -- it's a poor option.

The order in which the CSS selectors are applied should not make any difference (according to W3C specs.):

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Meaning that options #2 & #3 are functionally identical.

As for how you should utilise Bootstrap's 'container' class -- It depends on what sort of layout you wish to achieve --

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are required when using our default grid system. Choose from a responsive, fixed-width container (meaning its max-width changes at each breakpoint) or fluid-width (meaning it’s 100% wide all the time) [...]

Generally, the content(s) would be placed inside the container, for example:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Content here. -->
</div>
```

Which I suppose, would be option #5.

Comment: I would say 4 and your 5 are the same and the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

The use of Bootstrap's container is mostly based on the type of layout you want to create, and how you want properties to apply to your main elements.

On your example:

**Option #1** does not use containers, so it will not benefit at all from its main appeal which is *centering content*

**Option #2** and **Option #3** are the same since class order should not have any effect on your markup.

**Option #4** Can be used if you only want to center content, but keep other elements using the full available width, particularly helpful if you want sections to have different background colors for example but keeping the content in the center, like this:

[image]

The last option you have is to use `.container` on a global `div` or `section` so that ALL the content on your page stays centered.

Also, if you use `container-fluid`, the container will expand to use the full viewport width, which might be wanted for some layouts, as well as not working particularly well with others when the screen is too wide, ending up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: I didn’t know there was a global way to set a container.   Having said that I do have some content that is full width but that is the exception.  I mostly use option 4 above.

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't call it a *global way* per se, it's just boxing all the content in a main `div` to avoid repeating the `container` class every time on each section if you are going to center everything anyways

Comment: Repeating the container on each section is what I've done.  I'd like to clean it up if it can be overridden for the few instances I want full width display.  Is there a common place such as the main css file to set the container?  I have a header and footer included on each page so I guess I could put it in those if there's not a more elegant method.

Comment: Well, not exactly as you put it, remember that `container` is just another Bootstrap class, so what I mean is that, if you are going to center all the content on the page, regardless of styles, you can just create a global `div` or `section` o `main` etc, and add the `container` class in it, then all the additional elements you include inside that global `div` will be centered

Comment: In the case where you want to have a container just for the content but not for the whole section, then you would need to include it there *inside* the section, not globally

Comment: That's helpful.  Thanks for the example.